# How to pass a variable from .java file to .xml file in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android and I want to simulate a car steering wheel. I found it easy to insert an Image(of steering wheel) and use tween animation to rotate it though XML.

I measured the rotation of the phone using sensor classes in .java file.

Now I need to pass this measured value from `.java` file to `.xml` (under res\anim) so as to rotate the image as per the roation of the phone.

Kindly help me by advicing a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to pass calculated value to xml resource, since resources are static.

But you can load the xml animation with

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, id)
```

modify its [properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html)

and apply it to the desired view with

```
desiredView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, m1shk4 .But i need to cotinuosly change the angle of rotation as the phone is rotated :( . i think i should do the animation stuff through .java rather than .xml file . Do u have any better way to do this?

Comment: I started from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html#draw-with-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

M1shk4 and Chet Haase, as told  "It's impossible to pass calculated value to xml resource"

So to implement my requirement, we need to do it using code in . Java file.

The below was the code I got from Chet Haase:

```
public void turn()  
{ 
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(currentRotation, currentRotation + 30,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,nimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);     
currentRotation = (currentRotation + 30) % 360;     
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());     
anim.setDuration(1000);     
anim.setFillEnabled(true);      
anim.setFillAfter(true);     
turnImg.startAnimation(anim); 
}
```

Its working fine: )

For more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928412/android-rotate-imageview-i-cant-set-the-final-position-of-imageview-in-onanimati)