# how to spin/flip android imageView?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I am trying to spin/flip an imageView in a way in which the image in question(a card) flips to the other side of it ie a 3d spin animations along its Z axis. Is that possible?

I have written this code below but it only spins in 2d changing its orientation only and not its side.

```
// animations
    private static final float ROTATE_FROM = 0.0f;
    private static final float ROTATE_TO = -10.0f * 360.0f;
    private RotateAnimation mRotateAnimation;

mRotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        mRotateAnimation.setDuration((long)2 * 150);
        mRotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);


mCardImage.startAnimation(mRotateAnimation);
```

Comment: try this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928412/android-rotate-imageview-i-cant-set-the-final-position-of-imageview-in-onanimati